# Radio Button Data don't show in the second fieldset

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, radio-button

I'm trying to submit data to MySQL and for some reason the value is passing through in the first radio button `<fieldset>` but not in the other `<fieldset>`.  Here is my code to explain much further.

```
<?php
    require 'inc/database.php';

    $pdo = Database::connect();
    $getLikes = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM fieldTest ORDER BY id DESC');
    $getLikes->execute();

    if($getLikes->rowCount() > 0) {
        while ($row = $getLikes->fetch()) {

echo '<div>';
echo '<form>';
echo '<div>';
echo '<p>';
 echo '<label>I like...<br>';
echo $row['appleColor'];
echo '</label>';
echo '</p>';
echo '<br>';
echo '<p>';
 echo '<label>I like...<br>';
echo $row['appleLikes'];
echo '</label>';
echo '</p>';

echo '</div>';
echo '</form>';

echo '</div><!--end of container-->';
                        echo '<br>';


?>

<form method="POST" action="likespost.php">

<!--FirstFieldSet-->
<fieldset>
         <h2>What color of apples do you like?</h2>
            <div class="inline-field">
            <input type="radio" id=""  name="appleColor" value="Green"   >
            <label>Green</label>
            </div>
            <div class="inline-field">
            <input type="radio" id=""  name="appleColor" value="Red"   >
            <label>Red</label>
            </div>


</fieldset>
<!--SecondFieldSet-->
<fieldset>
         <h2>How do you like your apples?</h2>
            <div class="inline-field">
            <input type="radio" id=""  name="appleLikes" value="In a beer."   >
            <label>In a beer.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="inline-field">
            <input type="radio" id=""  name="appleLikes" value="As a juice."   >
            <label>As a juice.</label>
            </div>
            <div class="inline-field">
            <input type="radio" id="" name="appleLikes" >
            <label for="radio">Other</label>
            <input id="" type="text"   name="appleLikes" placeholder="Please Explain...">
            </div>
</fieldset>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Post Likes</button>

</form>
```

Here is the likespost.php that post the data to MySQL .

```
<?php
  require 'inc/database.php';

    if (!empty($_POST)) {

        $appleColor = $_POST['appleColor'];
        $appleLikes = $_POST['appleLikes'];



        $valid = true;

        if ($valid) {
            $pdo = Database::connect();
            $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
            $sql = 'INSERT INTO fieldTest (appleColor, appleLikes) values(?, ?)';
            $q = $pdo->prepare($sql);
            $q->execute(array($appleColor, $appleLikes));
            Database::disconnect();
            header('Location: fieldTest.php');
        }
    }


?>
```

Here is my SQL.

```
CREATE TABLE `fieldTest` (
    `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `appleColor` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    `appleLikes` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

why is that the first fieldset data get posted but the second one is blank?

Comment: because the name of the radios is the same as the text-input.

Comment: nothing to do with your problem, but: label `for` should have an id as value, not a type.

Comment: Wow!! Ok I didn't see that.  I updated the code.  But I'm getting a "on" where I echo $row['appleLikes'];.  For the label part you are right about the label for I'm getting to that next.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why you use same field name (appleLikes) for Radio buttons and text field?

You are actually getting the value of text field (which is blank), not the value of radio buttons as the text field comes after radio buttons.

Try to use different name for text field.

Comment: You are right I changed that and now I'm getting a "on" where I echo $row['appleLikes'];.